# C++ How to place data in vector of base class

Tags: c++

Here is my base class:

```
#include <string>
#include "DataStruct.h"
#include <vector>
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

namespace Vibranium {
    using namespace mysqlx;
    class MySQLTable {
    public:
        MySQLTable();
        virtual ~MySQLTable() = default;
        int Index;
        std::string tableName;
        DataStruct dataStruct;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataStruct>> Data;
        Table getTable(Session& conn) const;
        RowResult getAll(Session& conn) const;
        virtual void LoadTable(RowResult& res) {}
    };
}

#endif //VIBRANIUM_CORE_MYSQLTABLE_H
```

Which is representing all MySQL tables i might have. Take a look at `Data` vector of types `DataStruct`. I use `DataStruct` as a base struct because all tables will have different structure.

Here is base `DataStruct` struct:

```
namespace Vibranium{
    struct DataStruct{};
}
```

Than I define my first mysql tablle `Accounts`:

```
#include <string>
#include "Database/DataStruct.h"
#include "Database/MySQLTable.h"


namespace Vibranium{
    using namespace std;
    struct AccountsStruct : DataStruct{
        int id;
        std::string email;
        std::string warTag;
        int state;
        std::string name;
        std::string lastname;
        std::string country;
        int dob_month;
        int dob_day;
        int dob_year;
        double balance;
        std::string created_at;
        std::string updated_at;
        int account_role;
        int rank;
        int playerRole;
    };


    class Accounts : public MySQLTable{
    public:
        Accounts() = default;
        void LoadTable(RowResult& res) override;
    };

}
```

As you can see inside I have defined `AccountsStruct` as child of `DataStruct`.
Here is how I implement `LoadTable`:

```
#include "Accounts.h"

using namespace Vibranium;

void Vibranium::Accounts::LoadTable(RowResult &res) {

        std::vector<AccountsStruct> accounts;
        AccountsStruct accountsStruct;
        for (Row row : res.fetchAll()){
            accountsStruct.id = row[0].get<int>();
            accountsStruct.email = row[1].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct.warTag = row[2].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct.state = row[4].get<int>();
            accountsStruct.name = row[5].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct.lastname = row[6].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct.country = row[7].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct.dob_month = row[8].get<int>();
            accountsStruct.dob_day = row[9].get<int>();
            accountsStruct.dob_year = row[10].get<int>();
            accountsStruct.balance = row[11].get<double>();
            accountsStruct.created_at = row[12].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct.updated_at = row[13].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct.account_role = row[15].get<int>();
            accountsStruct.rank = row[16].get<int>();
            accountsStruct.playerRole = row[17].get<int>();
            accounts.push_back(accountsStruct);
        }
}
```

As `Accounts` is child of `MySQLTable`

1. I would like to add all the data from `std::vector<AccountsStruct> accounts` into `Data` vector inherited from `MySQlTable`.
2. Also after that I would like to cycle thru the vector `Data` as it
   is of type `Accounts` instead of `MySQLTable` class. However I don't
   know how can I achieve those two things.

Is it possible and how?

Comment: In your second question do you mean to ask if you can iterate through a vector or type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataStruct>>` as if it were a vector of type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Accounts>>` or something else?

Comment: note that `unique_ptr` have to own created object. ANd to iterate , you have to use casts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would drop the type `DataStruct`, and make MySqlTable a template.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>
#include <memory>

namespace Vibranium {
    using mysqlx::Table;
    using mysqlx::RowResult;
    using mysqlx::Session;

    class MySQLTableBase {
    public:
        MySQLTableBase();
        virtual ~MySQLTableBase() = default;
        Table getTable(Session& conn) const;
        RowResult getAll(Session& conn) const;

        int Index;
        std::string tableName;
    };

    template <typename T>
    class MySQLTable : public MySQLTableBase {
    public:
        virtual void LoadTable(RowResult& res) = 0;

        T dataStruct; // What is this?
        std::vector<T> Data; // You don't need vector of pointers
    };
}
```

Then you define `Account` and `Accounts` as

```
#include <string>
#include "Database/MySQLTable.h"

namespace Vibranium{
    struct Account{
        int id;
        std::string email;
        std::string warTag;
        int state;
        std::string name;
        std::string lastname;
        std::string country;
        int dob_month;
        int dob_day;
        int dob_year;
        double balance;
        std::string created_at;
        std::string updated_at;
        int account_role;
        int rank;
        int playerRole;
    };

    class Accounts : public MySQLTable<Account>{
    public:
        Accounts() = default;
        void LoadTable(RowResult& res) override;
    };
}
```

Comment: Yea but I have this in class called `LoginDatabase` which is holding data of all tables `vector<unique_ptr<MySQLTable>> _tables;` If I make `MySQLTable` a template class than I can't make a vector containing all tables. Am I right ?

Comment: You can move the parts that don't depend on T into a `MySqlTableBase` base class. see edit

Comment: Aha! So you suggest to split `MySQLTable` into two. one as a template class one as a base class, right ?

Comment: Yes. I suspect the only place that needs to use `getTable` and `getAll` are methods of `MySQLTable`? You should get used to using the most restrictive access as possible in C++, rather than having everything public like Python forces

Comment: By restrictive you mean visibility or in general ?

Comment: Yes, something other than public

Comment: On another hand. In C++ can you have multiple inheritance? Like Accounts -> MySQlTable -> MySQLTableBase ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221208/discussion-between-caleth-and-venelin-vasilev).

Answer (score 0):

So, have fun with C++!

1. You don't have a vector in MySQLTable with name "Data". You have method (Data) returning vector of ... To implement your request you should create method (for example) void SetData(...).
2. You can't. You can cycle through vector of Data and cast (for example static_cast, or other) each element from Data to AccountStruct. WARNING! Wrong cast operation may cause undefined behavior, crashes, etc.!

Comment: I've eddited `Data` and it's now vector. Check the edited question. And this cast approach seems bad to me either. Can you suggest any other way of how can I basically load my MySQL table data and load it in vector of struct?

Comment: in my humble opinion, you try to make Python-like from C++ (it isn't good idea). I don't know your task/ideas for good advise, :(. May be you can store account data into Accounts class (create personal vector for accounts).

Comment: Okay so Accounts class inherit of MySQLTable ? Is that your idea and then Accounts to have it's own vector ?

Comment: Yes, it's one of solutions :).